# How do I pass a variable's value to html->link() $title?

Tags: html, cakephp, hyperlink, helper

My code looks like this:

```
<li>
    <?php echo $html-> link($post['Post']['title'], array('action'=>'post', $post['Post']['id'])); ?>
</li>
```

I'm trying to get a link in the form of `/cake/posts/view/<id>`, where id is 1, 2, 3 etc.

The error Cake gives is

> Error: Call to a member function link() on a non-object

Full code here: http://pastebin.com/hexVvkfk

Comment: What version of CakePHP are you using?

Answer (score 4):

You don't create links with `$html-> link`. Links are created by the HtmlHelper, which is an extension to your View object, so you'll need to use `$this->Html->link` from your view file.

Furthermore, you seem to be mixing up the action with your controller. To achieve what you want you'll more likely need:

```
echo $this->Html->link($post['Post']['title'], array(
    'controller' => 'posts', // Optional if already in the PostsController
    'action'=>'view',
    $post['Post']['id']
));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$this->Html->link(__('View', true), array('action'=>'post', $post['Post']['id']))
```

The argument is `post.id`, and it is passed into `/cake/posts/view/[Args]` when you click the 'View' link.

Answer (score 2):

### Helpers are view properties, not variables

The version of CakePHP is not mentioned but the way helpers are used changed from this:

```
$html->...
```

To this:

```
$this->Html->...
```

This syntax was [introduced in 1.3](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/new-features-in-cakephp-1-3.html#view-helpers), and the older `$html->...` support removed in 2.0. To correct the error simply replace all `$html` with `$this->Html` and the same for all other helpers.